# MySQL: Query in a Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Easy question, still I can't figure it out. I have two tables.

```
Table items: id (INT), text (VARCHAR)
Table shared: type (VARCHAR), account (VARCHAR), id (INT)
```

Explanation:

- Table **items** contains a list of tweets.
- Table **shared** contains a list of all tweets that have been shared (sent to Twitter).

Now I need to have a query that gives me the oldest text (smallest "id") from the **items** table that has not been used for a specific "type" and "account" in the **shared** table.

Example:

The database looks like this. There are two items in the **items** table and no items have been shared yet.

```
Table items: [[1, "First Tweet"], [2, "Second Tweet"]]
Table shared: []
```

Running the query will give back [1, "First Tweet"]. After that, I will insert a value in the shared table so it looks like this:

```
Table items: [[1, "First Tweet"], [2, "Second Tweet"]]
Table shared: [["twitter", "my-twitter-account", 1]]
```

Running the query again will give back [2, "Second Tweet"]. After that, I will insert a value in the shared table so it looks like this:

```
Table items: [[1, "First Tweet"], [2, "Second Tweet"]]
Table shared: [["twitter", "my-twitter-account", 1], ["twitter", "my-twitter-account", 2]]
```

I know I could do it by first pulling all "id"s from the **items** table, put them in an array and then check whether an "id" is in the **shared** table, but I think that is a horrible solution... the table will grow up to about 10,000 items max.

**SOLUTION**

Edit: I modified JW.'s code a bit and it works perfectly. Thanks!

My query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.text, MIN(a.id) ID
FROM    items a
        LEFT JOIN shared b
            ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `INSERT..INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO shared (type, account, id)
SELECT 'twitter' type, 'my-twitter-account' account, MIN(a.id) ID
FROM    items a
        LEFT JOIN shared b
            ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Okay, that is a bit too fast for me. I'd like to receive the "id" and the "text" from the **items** table as output first, then try posting it on twitter and *only if it succeeds insert it to the **shared** table.* Of course I know how to insert it afterwards, that's one of the easier queries :)

Edit: I think I figured it out on my own, thanks to your code!